# Resetting the sidebar between \lecture{}s

Tags: beamer, navigation, sidebar

I would like to break my course into separate lectures using \include and \includeonlylecture, which work fine, but the sidebar (using PaloAlto) fills up with the entire course contents and is unusable.

How can I reset the sidebar between \lecture{}s so that it has only the contents of the current lecture and not the contents of the entire course?

My reason for using \include{}s is so that I can put in references between the lectures.  For example, see Lecture 03 Frame 27.  Those I can generate myself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a course with many lectures.  Each is in its own .tex file which I \include{..} in the main file processed by pdflatex.  This allows me to create references between the lecture slides, while still being able to process a single lecture using \includeonlylecture{...}.  The problem is that this creates a huge sidebar navigation column and I'd like to reset it to empty between \lecture{...} commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a (possibly empty) part between your lectures:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\begin{document}
    
\lecture{lec 1}{lec1}
\section{title 1}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\lecture{lec 2}{lec2}
\part{}
\section{title 2}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```